# Finding the number of integer points inside a sphere of radius R and dimension D centered at the Origin

Tags: geometry, number-theory, computational-geometry

I am writing a computer program to count the number of integer points inside a sphere of radius R and Dimension D centered at the origin. In essence, if we have a sphere of dimension 2 (circle) and radius 5, I am determining all integer solutions to the inequality $X^{2} + Y^{2} \leq 25 $. Instead of counting every possible integer point, is there an efficient way to count the points ? Using symmetry ?

Comment: By symmetry you can count only 1/8 of the original, through reflection.

Comment: @user3313320 Can you give me an example for a computation with a sample radius / dimension ?

Comment: You just need to compute X from 0 to floor(R^2/2) and seek for corresponding Y.